# What spice rub would be typically Thai?

Tags: spices, pork, sous-vide

I'm trying to recreate a dish I had at [Alinea](http://www.alinea-restaurant.com/) a while ago. Their forum actually had a [good start for this dish](http://alineamosaic.com/forum/index.php?showtopic=857&view=&hl=curried%20pork&fromsearch=1&s=427ad1e7272fa8a48d216df5070d2910):

> The garnishes on the surface are
>   Hawaiian volcanic salt, cucumber,
>   garlic chips, fresh banana, young
>   coconut, red onion, lime segments with
>   zest, toasted cashews, and red chili
>   pudding. The glass circle contains a
>   basil seed-lime vinaigrette.
>
> We press the herbs in between two
>   pieces of rice paper to form the
>   centerpiece. Once the frame is
>   assembled the server drapes the flag
>   over the frame. We cure the pork belly
>   with salt, sugar and aromatics. It is
>   cooked sous vide until tender, seared
>   and shredded. We make a curry sauce
>   from coconut, ginger, mint,
>   lemongrass, thai chilis, kaffir lime,
>   cardamom, coriander, and lime juice.
>   We mix the curry with the shredded
>   pork belly to make the ragu spooned
>   over tableside by the service staff.

My question is, what would be a typical set of Thai aromatics for the pork prior to putting it in the sous vide?

Answer (score 4):

I think of the typical Thai flavor profile as garlic, ginger, lemongrass, some kind of spicy pepper, and Thai basil.

Answer (score 2):

You actually have a good "list" already in your question... the spices in the "curry sauce" minus the coconut and lime juice would make a nice Thai dry spice rub.  You could add a little salt and a couple whole green peppercorns or cracked black peppercorn as well.

> ginger, mint, lemongrass, thai chilis,
>   kaffir lime, cardamom, coriander

Answer (score 0):

The basic set of definitevely Thai flavours goes more or less like this:

- Lemongrass
- Galangal
- Kaffir lime leaves (use like bay leaves)
- Fish sauce
- Hot pepper
- Garlic
- Coriander seed (ground)
- Cardamom and Cinnamon as finishings

The above is basically my recipe for Thai curry paste, which I use for making noodles with or without coconut milk.

You can generally use ginger as a substitute for Galangal and soy sauce as a substitute for fish sauce, but that loses the Thai distinction and beocmes generally southeast-asian.